# Weekly calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

There are a million posts on how to get the current day of the week here on Stack, and I've been through all of them to no avail. I'm going through the API to and I'm still not seeing how to do this.

I need to setup a weekly calendar with Java. So if Sunday was the 29th, Monday will be the 30th, Tues the 31st OR 1st, and Wed the 1st or 2nd and so on.

So what I need to do is get the first day of the week (Sunday, which would correspond to 1 in the `Calendar._DAY_OF_WEEK`), its day of the month (Which would be `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`), and the next six days after that, taking into account the possibility that a new month could start.

I know this sounds simple but I've been scrounging around StackOverflow for hours now and amazingly I haven't found anything like this.

Comment: So what have you tried and what problem are you having?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Joda Time - it'll be significantly easier to use than java.util.Calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get the days of the current week.

```
private Locale locale = Locale.UK;
// 1. create calendar
private Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(locale);
private DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);

public void getThisWeeksDays() {
    // 2. set calendar to the current date
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);

    // 3. set calendars dOW field to the first dOW (last sunday)
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        // 4. get some infomation
        String nameOfMonth = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, locale);
        String nameOfDay = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, locale);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        System.out.println(dayOfMonth + ": " + df.format(cal.getTime()));

        // 5. increase day field; add() will adjust the month if neccessary
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
1: Sunday, 1 December 2013
2: Monday, 2 December 2013
3: Tuesday, 3 December 2013
4: Wednesday, 4 December 2013
5: Thursday, 5 December 2013
6: Friday, 6 December 2013
7: Saturday, 7 December 2013
```

Comment: Works for me (added text).

Answer (score 2):

### Joda-Time

Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 rather than the notoriously bad java.util.Date/Calendar classes bundled with Java.

I'm assuming you want only dates, without regard for time and time zones.

### First Day Of Week

This example assumes you want to hard-code a day of the week (Sunday or Monday etc.) as the beginning and ending of a week.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.


org.joda.time.LocalDate now = new org.joda.time.LocalDate();
org.joda.time.LocalDate monday = now.withDayOfWeek(org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
org.joda.time.LocalDate sunday = now.withDayOfWeek(org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY);

System.out.println("now: " + now);
System.out.println("Monday: " + monday);
System.out.println("Sunday: " + sunday);
```

When run…

```
now: 2013-11-30
Monday: 2013-11-25
Sunday: 2013-12-01
```

Be aware that not everyone starts the week with Sunday. Americans tend to use Sunday, Europeans Monday, and for some others Saturday. Monday is the international standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

I tried to find a way to soft-code the first/last day of week, but failed. The following code seemed promising, but I cannot find a way to pass a Locale.

```java
org.joda.time.LocalDate today = new org.joda.time.LocalDate();
org.joda.time.LocalDate weekStart = today.dayOfWeek().withMinimumValue();
org.joda.time.LocalDate weekEnd = today.dayOfWeek().withMaximumValue();
```

### Days Of The Week

To complete your question, add a For() loop and Bob's your uncle.

```java
System.out.println( "Week…" );
for ( int x = 0; x < 7; x = x + 1 ) {
    org.joda.time.LocalDate someDate = monday.plusDays( x );
    System.out.println( "Jour: " + someDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText( Locale.FRANCE ) + "  " + someDate.toString() );
}
```

When run…

```
Week…
Jour: lundi  2013-11-25
Jour: mardi  2013-11-26
Jour: mercredi  2013-11-27
Jour: jeudi  2013-11-28
Jour: vendredi  2013-11-29
Jour: samedi  2013-11-30
Jour: dimanche  2013-12-01
```